# Download OpenVPN client using Azure Powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-networking, azure-powershell

I am learning Azure Powershell and I want to download the VPN client files for the gateway using Powershell. As per Microsoft this can be done with `New-AzureRmVpnClientConfiguration` but I could not find much detail on how to download the client. Can anybody guide me to a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific need you want to use Powershell for downloading VPN client? Also, the command you mention is for creating a new VPN connection.

Comment: no specific need, just for learning purpose i want to use it. this command will be used as per microsoft article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-openvpn-clients

Comment: Have you already checked this Microsoft docs article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/new-azurermvpnclientconfiguration?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Answer (score 2):

you can use following command in order to download VPN client:

$cert=New-AzureRmVpnClientConfiguration -ResourceGroupName Group1 -AuthenticationMethod EAPTLS -Name newGW

$cert.VpnProfileSASUrl

source: https://babarmunir.wordpress.com/2018/12/30/configure-openvpn-for-azure-point-to-site-vpn-gateway-using-power-shell/

Comment: Ha!  That's a good little powershell ditty.  Tried to figure out that one a year ago and gave.  Thanks and cheers!